# Beginner haskell code is totally incorrect

Tags: haskell

I'm really new to haskell. Tried to implement something really simple with recursion. A function that returns the index of the first matching value in a list. The code below won't work, not sure why, does anyone know How I could correct this code?

```
linear_search :: (Eq a) => a -> [a] -> a
linear_search b w = linear_search_tail 0 b w
  where linear_search_tail :: (Eq a) => a -> a -> [a] -> a
        linear_search_tail x y [] = -1
        linear_search_tail x y (z:zs)
          | y == z = x
          | otherwise = linear_search_tail (x+1) y zs

main :: IO ()
main = print (linear_search 1 [2,5,4,3,7,3,1,2,3,4,5,7,8])
```

EDIT: Got it working. this is the correct code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env runghc

linear_search :: (Eq a) => a -> [a] -> Int
linear_search b w = linear_search_tail 0 b w
  where linear_search_tail :: (Eq a) => Int -> a -> [a] -> Int 
        linear_search_tail x y [] = -1
        linear_search_tail x y (z:zs)
              | y == z = x
              | otherwise = linear_search_tail (x+1) y zs

main :: IO ()
main = print (linear_search 1 [2,5,4,3,7,3,1,2,3,4,5,7,8])
```

Comment: @paxdiablo  it uses tail recursion which means no stack overflow and no pun intended. No pun intended.

Comment: It's helpful to potential answerers if you include the error message. ["Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, *a specific problem or error* and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself."](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @paxdiablo Evaluating this function in Haskell uses constant space without blowing the stack. The Haskell standard library implementation of the same function calls [`findIndices` which uses recursion](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/src/Data-List.html#findIndices).

Comment: @paxdiablo Well, since we can't use anything other than recursion, I suppose we're stuck.

Comment: @paxdiablo There is no call stack in Haskell.

Comment: My comment @paxdiablo was incorrect. Haskell has no stack. Tail recursion in this case does nothing to optimize.

Comment: @BrianYeh Haskell does have a stack, it just isn't a call stack.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code is searching for the index of a number, which means is should return an `Int`:

```
linear_search :: (Eq a) => a -> [a] -> Int
```

There's also a similar problem, see if you can find out!

> `linear_search_tail :: (Eq a) => Int -> a -> [a] -> Int`

Answer (score 3):

Let me add some comments on the corrected code:

```
linear_search :: (Eq a) => a -> [a] -> Int
linear_search b w = linear_search_tail 0 b w
  where linear_search_tail :: (Eq a) => Int -> a -> [a] -> Int 
        linear_search_tail x y [] = -1
        linear_search_tail x y (z:zs)
              | y == z = x
              | otherwise = linear_search_tail (x+1) y zs
```

In the auxiliary function, the second parameter `y` is passed around unchanged, so it's always equal to `b`. You can remove the parameter and directly use that:

```
linear_search :: (Eq a) => a -> [a] -> Int
linear_search b w = linear_search_tail 0 w
  where -- linear_search_tail :: (Eq a) => Int -> [a] -> Int 
        linear_search_tail x [] = -1
        linear_search_tail x (z:zs)
              | b == z    = x
              | otherwise = linear_search_tail (x+1) zs
```

(Here I had to remove/comment the inner type signature since Haskell interprets the inner `a` type variable to be independent from the outer `a` -- you can state that these are the same by enabling an extension, but let's keep it simple and just omit the signature.)

The above function returns `-1` on error. This is not idiomatic in Haskell, where it is more common to return a `Maybe Int`, which is a type containing values representing integers `Just 0, Just 1, Just 2, ...` plus a distinct value `Nothing` that can be interpreted as "no result". If we use that we get:

```
linear_search :: (Eq a) => a -> [a] -> Maybe Int
linear_search b w = linear_search_tail 0 w
  where linear_search_tail x [] = Nothing
        linear_search_tail x (z:zs)
              | b == z    = Just x
              | otherwise = linear_search_tail (x+1) zs
```

Note that this will make life *less* convenient for the caller, which now gets its index wrapped in a `Just` box, or `Nothing`. This is actually a good thing, since now the caller can not easily forget to check for the "not found" case and use a plain integer pretending it's not `-1`. The caller is now forced to use something like

```
case linear_search 1 [2,3,4,5] of
   Just x  -> "Found at position " ++ x
   Nothing -> "Not found!"
```

Finally, note that the first line

```
linear_search b w = linear_search_tail 0 w
```

can also be written as

```
linear_search b = linear_search_tail 0
```

That is, you can omit the same variable(s) in the trailing position of a definition. This is called eta-reduction, and does not necessarily make your code look better. In this case, it's not helping much. I just mention it since you may see some code like this in the future.

---

After you learn some more Haskell, you might want to know how to exploit library functions for this. For instance, the `elemIndex` library function from `Data.List` performs the linear search you are trying to write. Alternatively,

```
linear_search :: (Eq a) => a -> [a] -> Maybe Int
linear_search x xs = case filter ((x ==) . snd) $ zip [0..] xs of
                     []       -> Nothing
                     (i, _):_ -> Just i
```

You probably find this unreadable right now, but you can go on with your learning and get back at this later on when you are more familiar with Haskell. In the meantime, writing recursive functions as you did is the right approach.

Comment: Check the "Here's another one" example: you are matching against a List and a Tuple. Also the Int is really in the first position of the pair, not the second. That won't typecheck. You probably meant "  ((i, _):xs) -> Just i"

Comment: Also check the first example of the library example: "find" returns the matching element, not its index. This also doesn't typecheck.

Comment: You still have the "i" in the second position and it should be in the first. It is just not your day it seems.

Comment: Great comment. I actually made another minor style improvement to the code. 

for "linear_search b = linear_search_tail 0"
you can actually just write "linear_search = linear_search_tail 0"

Comment: For the comment above... There's an additional edit...  you actually have to make additional changes to the example your example to get it to work.  The guard will have to be changed from "| b == z    = Just x" to "| x == z    = Just x"